# Why can't we use the "controller as" syntax in AngularJS when replacing "this" with $scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Consider this :

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="some">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="helloCtrl as hello">
      <label>Name:</label>
      <h1>Hello {{hello.yourName}}!</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    angular.module("some", []).controller("helloCtrl", function($scope){
        $scope.yourName = 'Alice'
    })

</script>
</html>
```

1. If I change  `$scope.yourName = 'Alice'` to  `this.yourName = 'Alice'`, it works. Why not before ?
2. Similarly, if I keep `$scope.yourName = 'Alice'`and still use the **as controller** syntax, it doesn't work.

I am asking because I read somewhere that `this` is set to `$scope` by AngularJS internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, an optional exercise to "peek under the hood". If you're using Chrome, install [Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en), inspect your controller div and have a look at the `$scope` tab. If you're not using `controllerAs`, you'll see all your controller properties, but if you're not, you'll only see a single property with a name corresponding to your controller alias. All your properties will then be below this in the tree.

A thing that is easy to forget with Angular is that controllers are just JS objects, instantiated by Angular when your page loads. In your first example, when your controller is instantiated it adds the `yourName` property to the `$scope` object that was passed to the constructor. To get the value of this property, use `$scope.yourName` - although within your handlebars, Angular will add the `$scope.` prefix for you.

> I read somewhere that this is set to $scope by AngularJS internally

This is where the misunderstanding is. In the second example, `yourName` is a property of your *controller*, **not** a property of `$scope`. This is where `controllerAs` comes in - no magic, just a little syntactic sugar. Here, when the controller is instantiated and its properties set with `this`, Angular creates a property on `$scope` with the name corresponding to `controllerAs` and a value of your controller object. The value of this property is therefore at `$scope.hello.yourName` - hence writing `hello.yourName` in your handlebars.

Sources:

[Angular Controller Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) - Lots of obvious "how", but there's a little (rather dry!) info on how things work underneath

[The Angular Style Guide on Controllers](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#controllers) - Required reading for Angular devs IMO. Explains a lot of the "why" clearly and concisely, as well as the "how".

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `$scope` is tied to scope, so if you have something like this in your controller:

```
$scope.Alice = "Alice";
```

you use this in HTML:

```
{{ Alice }}
```

But if you use `this`, it's not tied to the scope anymore and your controller has

```
this.Alice
```

then you write it as `{{ controllerAlias.Alice }}` to tell Angular it's part of controller, not of scope.(i.e. just `Alice` won't work anymore).

About the second part of your question, you could use `hello.Alice` without using alias by doing this:

```
$scope.hello = this;
```

This is implicitly done when using `controller as`(it wasn't there in older versions of Angular).

Comment: The `$scope.hello = this` means you're basically writing `$scope.hello.Alice = "Alice"` when you write `this.Alice = "Alice"`. Obviously it's going to get accessed in HTML as `{{ hello.Alice }}`.